# Exactly 1008 edges from any vertex in $Q_{2016}$

Tags: graph-theory

Recall that the cube $Q_n$ is the simple graph with $V(G_n) = {0, 1}^n$ in
which two vertices are adjacent if and only if they differ in exactly one
coordinate. Prove that the edges of $Q_{2016}$ can be oriented in such a way that there will be exactly 1008 edges going out of any vertex.

Answer (score 2):

Every vertex has even degree, so $Q_{2016}$ has an Eulerian circuit.
Walking this circuit and orienting each edge in the direction you are traveling gives the desired orientation.